# nestJS set nullable value null in mysql database

Tags: mysql, express, nestjs, entity, dto

I have the following problem. In my entity I have set the refine_set and refined_vnum fields to nullabe & in my CreateItemProtoDto to IsOptional(). In create everything works now and I don't have to pass these two values.

```
export class CreateItemProtoDto {
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  readonly refined_vnum: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  readonly refine_set: number;
}
```

But if I set them once and don't give them in a patch request I want them to be set to null again in the mysql database. But this does not happen because the Dto does not consider the record because it is zero.

```
export class UpdateItemProtoDto extends PartialType(CreateItemProtoDto) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply update your DTO class to have default values.

When passing the actual value from the request that one will be overridden otherwise it will remain `null`.

```js
export class CreateItemProtoDto {
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  readonly refined_vnum: number | null = null;

  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  readonly refine_set: number | null = null;
}
```

Comment: Works just like i needed it!